# How get a statistical summary from List of Maps in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Using the following List of Maps, I would like to create a kind of statistical summary in order to be able to create a plot from it.

```
    List<dynamic> data = [
  {
    "SoftwareVersion": "10.09.21",
    "Controller": "P1",
  },
  {
    "SoftwareVersion": "11.11.03",
    "Controller": "P1",
  },
  {
    "SoftwareVersion": "11.11.03",
    "Controller": "P2",
  },
  {
    "SoftwareVersion": "28.09.04",
    "Controller": "P2",
  },
  {
    "SoftwareVersion": "28.09.04",
    "Controller": "P2",
  },
  {  
    "SoftwareVersion": "28.09.04",
    "Controller": "P3",  
  }];
```

The expected outcome from the list above should look like the list below. So that for each available controller I get a count for the actual used SoftwareVersion.

```
List newData = [
{
  "P1": {
    "10.09.21": 1,
    "11.11.03": 1,
    },
  "P2": {
    "11.11.03": 1,
    "28.09.04": 2
    },
  "P3": {
    "28.09.04": 1
    } 
}];
```

Comment: @ArbiterChil the second List is the expected statistical outcome from the first list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the list adding to the `newData` map. Be careful to add an empty value if this controller or version hasn't been seen before - use the handy `putIfAbsent` for that. (Note that I removed the unnecessary outer list from `newData`);

```
void main() {
  data.forEach(addToNewData);
  print(newData);
}

void addToNewData(Map<String, String> e) {
  final version = e['SoftwareVersion']!;
  final controller = e['Controller']!;
  final controllerMap = newData.putIfAbsent(controller, () => <String, int>{});
  controllerMap[version] = controllerMap.putIfAbsent(version, () => 0) + 1;
}

final newData = <String, Map<String, int>>{};
```